# Shouldn't Apple consider allowing use of Apple Pencil while it's charging?

Tags: ipad, charging, ipados, apple-pencil

I have an iPad 2018 12.1.1 with 1st generation Apple Pencil. I am trying to use it for taking notes while it is connected to USB-cable charging, but surprisingly it doesn't work even though it is recognized by the iPad already! (I can see its charging status on notification page)

So I am wondering shouldn't Apple consider the issue and fix the problem?

Is it worth it contacting them for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Apple disables drawing functionality while Apple Pencil is charging for performance reasons. So, the behavior is by design.

- [Cannot use Apple Pencil while charging](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7408374?answerId=29590411022#29590411022)

> No, we disable the drawing functionality while it is charging (performance reasons). Although you can charge with a Lightning cable, it will charge much faster when connected directly to the iPad Pro.

In case you find a product feature concerning, you can always share feedback with Apple using the Product Feedback webpage:

- [Product Feedback - Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)

Comment: oh too bad to hear that!
thanks for the link

Comment: That discussion link is wrong. Apple Pencil gen 1 fast charges from USB as well as from iPad. Also, it gets like 5 to 15 minutes of charge in 60 seconds, so you don’t lose much time waiting for a charge up unless you need a repair in my experience.